# What would this breadboard look like as a schematic?

Tags: resistors, schematics, breadboard, button, diagram

Here is my button pull-up resistor circuit on a breadboard. Note both the additional link between the button and ground, and the multimeter measurement point is different.

[image: Button pull-up resistor]

I was wondering what the breadboard above would look like in a circuit schematic. Here's my current attempt:

[image]

I feel unconfident about my results since it looks too simple. How can this be improved?

Comment: It's missing the switch. Kind of important.

Comment: How about the resistor value?  Each diagram has a different value.

Comment: also, I will complain about every schematic where components have no name! You should call your resistor "R1", at the very least. This might seem silly since there's only one resistor in your schematic now, but as soon as you have two of the same value, you need to start referring to them by some weird construct like "the 4.7 kΩ resistor on the top right, next to the diodes, but not the one below the transistor".

Comment: If you don't understand your switch: the symbol used in your breadboard drawing program is not good (it's confusing instead). It hides the fact that the two contacts that are on the left side (as the switch is currently rotated in your drawing) are actually connected, and the two contacts on the right side are connected, and the actual switch is between; would you have the switch in your hand, you could try with a multimeter set to check for connectivity :)  *Can you guess why engineers want schematics, and not breadboard drawings?*

Comment: The longer line in the battery symbol is normally the positive terminal, and we normally show the more positive voltage at the top of the schematic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the missing component in your schematic:[image]

The positive (red) wire of the voltage source is connected to one terminal of the resistor, the other terminal of the resistor is connected to both the voltmeter and one terminal of the switch, the other terminal of the switch is connected to both the negative terminal of the voltmeter and the negative terminal to the voltmeter (black).

Comment: You have shown a Normally Closed button.  A normally open switch as the OP used would be drawn so that pushing the button/moving contact would close the contacts.  In your drawing, the moving contact should be moved to the left of the vertical lines.

Comment: the battery symbol is incorrectly oriented in your schematic

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes you are right, the switch is a normally open switch and it's supposed to note that.

Comment: @jsotola never expected that this mistake would be in the schematic, but it's worth to note that a black line always represents a negative contact. No worries